# Authentication error when attempting to fetch google analytics 4 with app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-authentication, urlfetch, google-analytics-4

I would like to connect a community connector to a google analytics 4 account so that I can easily modify the data and send it to data studio. However, My code is returning an authentication error:

```
{ error: 
   { code: 401,
     message: 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
     status: 'UNAUTHENTICATED' } }
```

I have included the token, but I am unsure if I am making the correct url call or if there is some other issue that I am unaware of. I don't believe I need an API key to connect from community connector to a google API, but I may be wrong. I did create an API key but the result was the same.

```
function testFetch(){
  var url = "https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport"
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 
  var options = {
      "method" : 'POST',
      "entity": { "propertyId": "263290444" },
      "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-12-01", "endDate": "2021-03-01" }],
      "dimensions": [{ "name": "country" }],
      "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }],
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer' + token,
        },
      };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: I think that the reason of your error message is due to `Authorization: 'Bearer' + token,`. In this case, please add a space between `Bearer` and `token` like `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,`. But from your script, I'm not sure whether your `propertyId` and `token` can be used for requesting to the endpoint. I apologize for this.

Comment: Does app script support authorization to that api?   Can we see how you are authorizing the request?

Comment: @Tanaike The 401 error seemed to be caused by the Bearer token space. thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small guide on how to do what you are trying to achieve:

Set explicit OAuth scopes ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)) to your Apps Script project manifest (`appsscript.json`). In this case you need to add the following:

```json
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
  }
}
```

Then you need to separate the method parameters from the fetch options. The fetch options need to be stringified and added to `payload`. You also need to set the `contentType` to JSON.

```js
const options = {
  entry: { propertyId: "263290444"},
  // etc.
}
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  'https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    payload: JSON.stringify(options)
  }
)
```

After that, you may use the response as you were doing before.

Note that `Bearer` and the token need to be separated by a space, which your code does not have. It's hard to see because of the concatenation and that why I usually use template literals ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

### References

- [Authorization scopes | Set explicit scopes (Google Apps Script Guides)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params) (Google Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Template literals (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: thank you for the help it was very helpful and solved the 401 error issue. 
However, I am now receiving a 403 error regardless of the property I try to connect to, do you have any advice on what could cause that?

Comment: @Shan HTTP 403 (Forbidden) means you lack permissions for some reason (there are quite a lot of them, actually). The response body should have an explanation. Also If you find new problems, I'd advise to make a new question instead of asking in answers ;)

Comment: Yeah I figured I should ask another question after I posted that comment, so I did and I managed to get it all working. Thanks for the help!